# Is it possible to display vertex normals in object mode?

Tags: modifiers, add-on, normals, object-mode

I want to preview how vertex normals will look like after WeightedNormal modifier without actually applying it. Is there any way to do that?

I am aware about Y.A.V.N.E. addon but it hasn't been updated to work with 3.0. (yavne and blender face strengths are not the same which adds confusion).

"On Cage" button isn't an option because I might have some generative modifiers before the WeightedNormal.

Answer (score 0):

It takes a while to find it but it does work in Blender 3.0! Check in the Tool sidebar, under Workspace, and you can turn YAVNE back on. It will be in the Extended Tools panel, not in Tool anymore.

Comment: Can't get it to work. Can you please upload some screenshots with these settings and with YAVNE normals showing in the Object Mode?